# Print to a printer attached to the user's terminal in CentOS

Tags: printing

I have a server with SCO Unix 505 in which we run an application in Foxbase.  I've just installed CentOS 5.5 and made my Foxbase application work in Centos.  The problem is that in SCO Unix foxbase uses "lprint" command for printing to a printer attached to the user's terminal.  The lprint command doesn't exist in CentOS.  I've been trying to use CentOS lp and lpr commands without success.  Is there and alternative in CentOS for Unix "lprint" command ?

Comment: how about creating a wrapper `lprint` that calls `lp`?

Comment: apparently `lprint` is a glorified `cat` (it reads special `termcap` entries PN and PS that command the terminal to start sending data to local printer, and does some optional post-processing) --  http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/PR_admin/prntT.addlprint.html